# Add character before a very large file to send to a shell script

Tags: command-line, shell, shell-script

I am trying to run a shell script on a 31,65 Go json file.

```
./oetl.sh database.json
```

I need to have brackets before and after the file.

What I have in database.json :

```
{..},{..},..
```

What I want :

```
[{..},{..}..]
```

Is there any way to do this without editing the file ? 
If not, how can I edit the file fast ?

I know I can echo the closing bracket fast :

```
echo "]" >> database.json
```

How can I add the opening bracket ?

I don't know if this is needed and I am new to shell script but here is the oetl.sh file :

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# Copyright (c) 2014 Luca Garulli
#

#set current working directory
cd `dirname $0`

# resolve links - $0 may be a softlink
PRG="$0"

while [ -h "$PRG" ]; do
  ls=`ls -ld "$PRG"`
  link=`expr "$ls" : '.*-> \(.*\)$'`
  if expr "$link" : '/.*' > /dev/null; then
    PRG="$link"
  else
    PRG=`dirname "$PRG"`/"$link"
  fi
done

# Get standard environment variables
PRGDIR=`dirname "$PRG"`

# Only set ORIENTDB_HOME if not already set
[ -f "$ORIENTDB_HOME"/lib/orientdb-etl-@VERSION@.jar ] || ORIENTDB_HOME=`cd "$PRGDIR/.." ; pwd`
export ORIENTDB_HOME

# Set JavaHome if it exists
if [ -f "${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java" ]; then 
   JAVA=${JAVA_HOME}/bin/java
else
   JAVA=java
fi
export JAVA

ORIENTDB_SETTINGS="-Djava.util.logging.config.file="$ORIENTDB_HOME/config/orientdb-client-log.properties" -Djava.awt.headless=true"
JAVA_OPTS=-Xmx512m
KEYSTORE=$ORIENTDB_HOME/config/cert/orientdb-console.ks
KEYSTORE_PASS=password
TRUSTSTORE=$ORIENTDB_HOME/config/cert/orientdb-console.ts
TRUSTSTORE_PASS=password
SSL_OPTS="-Dclient.ssl.enabled=false -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=$KEYSTORE -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword=$KEYSTORE_PASS -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=$TRUSTSTORE -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword=$TRUSTSTORE_PASS"

$JAVA -server $JAVA_OPTS $ORIENTDB_SETTINGS $SSL_OPTS -Dfile.encoding=utf-8 -Dorientdb.build.number="@BUILD@" -cp "$ORIENTDB_HOME/lib/*" com.orientechnologies.orient.etl.OETLProcessor $*
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new file containing the content as you wish it. For your situation, this can be done like this:

```
echo "[" > database-new.json ; cat database.json >> database-new.json ; echo "]" >> database-new.json
```

`>` is create new file (clearing the file if existing) and direct `stdout` to it. `>>` is append `stdout` to file.

Comment: I was going to answer about the same command, but adding a comment explaining that shifting everything in the file does require rewriting the whole file, and there is no way around that.  There would be ways to do it in the same file if disk space is an issue but it would have to be done in a different language like C, PHP or many other languages to open the file in read-write mode.

Comment: @JuliePelletier If you want to try an alternate answer, I think named pipes might achieve the same thing without eating up disk space. I'm not all that familiar with using them myself.

Comment: Wow okey I didn't think about that thanks ! It makes sense.